# Is there any way to automatically move periods inside quotation marks? (csquotes doesn't seem to work)

Tags: latex, quotation-marks

`csquotes` doesn't work in this case, maybe because I'm using a custom command:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter, american]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[autopunct,style=american]{csquotes}
\newcommand{\qq}[1]{\textquote{#1}}
\begin{document}
This is an \qq{example}.
\end{document}
```

`\qq` will not move the trailing period into the quotation, e.g. `This is an \qq{example}.` will still yield `This is an “example”.` I have written a book using `\qq` and would like to change the quotation styles to one which moves periods and colons into the quotes. Is there a safe way to achieve this automatically? Maybe a package different from `csquotes`? The only solution I've found on the net so far didn't work with spacing correctly.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: I have changed the question accordingly. The `autopunct` option doesn't work. I'm looking for a robust solution that doesn't require me to change the markup (which may not include the period).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `csquotes` documentation, section 9.2:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[autopunct,style=american]{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6}
\newcommand{\qq}[1]{\textquote{#1}}
\begin{document}
This is an \qq{example}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! (Kind of strange they have a global option that only works when you redefine a command, but I should have checked the docs more carefully.)